# Sample from one of two distributions

Tags: r, probability, sampling

I want to repeatedly sample values based on a certain condition. For example I want to create a sample of 100 values. 
With probability of 0.7 it will be sampled from one distribution, and from another probability, otherwise.

Here is a way to do what I want:

```
set.seed(20)
A<-vector()

for (i in 1:100){
  A[i]<-ifelse(runif(1,0,1)>0.7,rnorm(1, mean = 100, sd = 20),runif(1, min = 0, max = 1))
}
```

I am sure there are other more elegant ways, without using for loop. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: "70% of the time it will be sampled from one distribution, and other 30% of the time from another." You need to be precise there. From your attempted solution it seems that 70/30% are supposed to be probabilities and not fixed values.

Comment: Exactly - probabilities and not fixed values. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 4):

You can sample an indiactor, which defines what distribution you draw from.

```
ind <- sample(0:1, size = 100, prob = c(0.3, 0.7), replace = TRUE)
A <- ind * rnorm(100, mean = 100, sd = 20) + (1 - ind) * runif(100, min = 0, max = 1)
```

In this case you don't use a for-loop but you need to sample more random variables.

Answer (score 2):

If the percentage of times is not random, you can draw the right amount of each distribution then shuffle the result :

```
n <- 100
A <- sample(c(rnorm(0.7*n, mean = 100, sd = 20), runif(0.3*n, min = 0, max = 1)))
```